# Update nested dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.7

What is the proper way of updating nested dict, so I have two dict

```
data = {
 'version': '2',
 'workflow': {'task_defaults': {'retry': {'count': 3, 'delay': 2}},
              'tasks': {'t1': {'action': 'postgres.export-db',
                               'input': {'database': 'prod',
                                         'filepath': '/var/tmp/prod-dump.pgsql',
                                         'host': 'postgres.local',
                                         'password': 'mypass',
                                         'username': 'myuser'},
                               'on-success': ['t2']},
                        't2': {'action': 'aws.upload-to-s3',
                               'input': {'sourcepath': '{{ tasks(t1).result.filepath }}',
                                         'targetpath': 's3://mybucket/prod-dump.pgsql'},
                               'on-success': ['t3'],
                               'retry': {'count': 5, 'delay': 5}},
                        't3': {'action': 'shell.command',
                               'input': {'cmd': 'rm {{ tasks(t1).result.filepath }}'},
                               'on-complete': ['t4']},
                        't4': {'action': 'notify.send-mail',
                               'input': {'from': 'bot@njinn.io',
                                         'message': 'DB Dump {{ tasks(t1).result.filepath }} was stored to S3',
                                         'subject': 'Prod DB Backup',
                                         'to': 'admin@njinn.io'},
                               'target': 'njinn'}}}}
```

and the other one

`new_data = {'action': '/srv/foo/', 'pack': 'name'}`

so I want to merge `new_data` into `input` dict inside `data`.

So `input` would look like this

```
{"input": {
          "action": "/srv/foo",
          "pack": "name",
          "target": "foo",
          "parameters": {
            "to": "admin@foo.io",
            "from": "bot@foo.io",
            "subject": "Prod DB Backup",
            "message": "DB Dump was stored to S3"
          }
     }
```

how can I achieve that, all tries failed, best solutions that I have is

`{key:dict(data.get(key,{}), **values) for key,values in new_data.items()}`

but that is not working, can someone explain how to do this, thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @ArpitSvt I don't have it, don't understand how to approach this

Comment: Where does the `...['input']['target'] == 'foo'` come from?  And where do the `parameters` come from?  Both is neither in `data` nor in `new_data`.

Comment: Which of the `input` key of data are you trying to update? All of them?

Comment: `for v in data['workflow']['tasks'].values(): v['input'].update(new_data)`? Edit: wait a minute where did all those extra stuff in your output come from?

Comment: @olinox14 all of them

Comment: I see an `'action'` inside the `'input'` dict in your expected output. But looking at the original data, all `'action'`s are outside their `'input'`. Is you expected result correct?

Comment: `action` outside the `input` are fine, they need to be there, I need to add more in the `input` so basically I want to merge key, value of new_data inside `input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the double star notation! If you just wanna merge the two dicts:

```
for key in data['workflow']['tasks']:
    data['workflow']['tasks'][key]['input'] = {**new_data, **data['workflow']['tasks'][key]['input']}
```

If you want the dict to look like your example (with `parameters`):

```
for key in data['workflow']['tasks']:
    data['workflow']['tasks'][key]['input'] = {**new_data, 'parameters': data['workflow']['tasks'][key]['input']}
```

Comment: ok thanks, for the example, it worked so at least I know in which directions I need to go